# Shortcode registered from a plugin not recognized

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, shortcode

I'm coding a really simple plugin to add some slideshows to my theme. I also want to register a shortcode to invoke them from my pages. So far I have this:

```
class Slideshow {

public function __construct() {

    // Register the project custom post type
    add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'ss_register_slideshow_type' ), 0 );
    add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'ss_register_shortcodes' ), 0 );
}

function ss_register_slideshow_type() {}

function ss_register_shortcodes() {
    add_shortcode( 'embed-slideshow', 'ss_shortcode_embed_slideshow' );
}

function ss_shortcode_embed_slideshow( $atts ) {
    return 'Foo';
}

}

// init
$slideshow_instance = new Slideshow();
```

I omit the custom post type registration for brevity. The custom post type gets registered, but when I try to call the shortcode in a page with

```
[embed-slideshow]
```

nothing happens. I mean, I get [embed-slideshow] written. I've registered another shortcode from my theme functions and it works well.

Am I missing something really obvious? Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: If I move the same functions to the the functions theme file, it works ok. So it must be something going on with the plugin creation.

Comment: Inside the plugins folder. The plugin has been activated, and as I said, the custom post type registration works.

At first I thought it had something to do with the priority, but I don't know anymore...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your shortcode action is wrong/incomplete:

```
function ss_register_shortcodes() {
    add_shortcode( 'embed-slideshow', array( $this, 'ss_shortcode_embed_slideshow' ) );
}
```

Since you are doing OOP, you have to use the class method in object context (or static).

Comment: To be honest, I've just started to code my custom plugins in an OOP fashion, and sometimes I completely forgot about those details. Thanks mate.